# Preventing mobile keyboard on input fields using datetimepicker by Tempus Dominus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use datetimepicker by [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) but whenever I try to pick a date from mobile the default keyboard opens and it hides the modal. I would like to prevent it from opening.

I already tried some workarounds I found online but I didn't get it to work. I also would like someone to explain how these workarounds work and why (because I did not understand them) before I apply them.

I tried to **readonly** the input field but then the modal does not open. I tried adding a second button and hide it *(with display none)* then trigger a click event on the readonly field and triggering the hidden button but that did not work either. I also tried adding a keypress event to prevent default but that only disables keyboard input on computers.

Javascript code for the events:

```
$('#datetime').keypress(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
  <input name="datetime" id="datetime" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetime">
  <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetime" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the modal from mobile to pop up but instead both modal and keyboard opens up every time I need to enter a **datetime**.

Comment: please check the answer below its works now there is no mobile keyboard will appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute `readonly` for avoiding mobile keyboard.

```js
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
    ignoreReadonly: true,
});
```

```css
input#datetime {
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input name="datetime" id="datetime" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetime" readonly="readonly">
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetime" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

you have an option to ignore the `readonly` input and open `datepicker` on button click.

Comment: As I mentioned above I already tried using **readonly** but then it doesn't open the modal as I am clicking it.

Comment: I have edit my answer I find solution of your Question. please try this code and update your reviews.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tempus Dominus, you can set the option focusOnShow to false. [Source](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Options/)

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  focusOnShow: false,
});
```